# Convert class instance to string upon storing in a MonogoDB

Tags: php, mongodb, bson

In PHP I have an some instances of a custom class (e.g. MediaUid) which I want to store in a MongoDB as a string in some nested document somewhere.

I know I can use `Serializable` class to serialize and store as a serialized object like in the example below, but is there also a way to automatically store it as a string (so without manually casting before inserting into the db)?

```
<?php

namespace Domain\Media\Models;

use MongoDB\BSON\Serializable;

class MediaUid implements Serializable
{

    public readonly string $val;

    public function __construct(string $val)
    {
        $this->val = $val;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->val;
    }

    public function bsonSerialize()
    {
        return ['val' => $this->val];
    }

}
```

In other words for this class `bsonSerialize` is called since it implements `Serializable`, but is there a way to make it call for example `__toString` instead?